# why is php-fpm running as nobody?

Tags: php-fpm, nobody

I recently installed php-fpm on my server (CENTOS 6.5 x86_64 standard, WHM 11.44.1 (build 7)) following the instructions here: http://infoliser.com/how-to-configure-apache-2-2-with-php-fpm-using-whm-cpanel-and-easyapache/

The server API, as revealed by `phpinfo()`, is now FPM/FastCGI.

However, when I run a php script containing `exec('id')`, I get:

`uid=99(nobody) gid=99(nobody) groups=99(nobody)`

I got the impression that php-fpm would run as the uid of the owner of the php script, rather than as the owner of the http process (as in this case). This page http://php-fpm.org/ says fpm has the "Ability to start workers with different uid/gid/chroot/environment and different php.ini (replaces safe_mode)".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: php-fpm has its own configuration file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

PHP-FPM does not execute the script as the owner of the script, but as the user configured in the matching pool config.

On my Debian system, the default pool `www` is defined in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` and contains:

```
; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

Yours will probably have `user=nobody` and `group=nobody`.
You can create more pools and use them by assigning them in your Apache/NGINX/whatever configs.